# i have table with 100 million records i have application it will analysis the table and give the statistics of the table

Tags: postgresql

i am using postgres db. i have table with 100 million records. that table have 52 columns including 1 or 2 unique column. and i have the application it will analysis the table and it give the result how much total distinct values are there in that table.

and also it will give how much pattern, datatype...etc
but when i use that table in that application it taking 5days to give result.because in backend it will execute 100 query in that db. specially one query taking 3days.

how to improve the performance of the query to fetch the result.

i tried index but it also taking same time (5days).

**can i create index if the table having records? if yes means which type of index i need to create.**

how to improve the performance of the query index or partition or anything else.

if i need to create index/partition means which type of index/partition i need to create?

Comment: What is 10 crore? And what about the datamodel, the DDL and your queries? Without that information, nobody has any idea how to help you.

Comment: i am not doing any update on that table. it that application will execute only select type of ddl command only.

Comment: An update can take a decade or so, if the record you want to update is locked by another proces. We have no clue what is going on. But a query that takes hours on a small database, smells like issues with locks or queries.

Comment: crore means count like 10millions equal to 1crore, what i said means i have 100 millions of records in my table.

Comment: @frank heikens, we are not doing any update anything in that table.

Comment: Could you update your question and show us something? The only thing I know so far, is that you have a database and that you have a problem. I'd like to help, but you have to give us some information. Show us the datamodel, show us the SQL, show us the results from EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) etc.

Comment: "*can i create index if the table having records?*" - yes, of course. What makes you think this isn't possible?

Comment: `... that table have 52 columns including 1 or 2 unique column.` <<-- And what is the *cardinality* of these 50 columns?

Answer (score 1):

The pg_stats view will do this for you.

```
select * 
from pg_stats 
where tablename = 'stable'
```

gives something like this.

```
Name                  |Value                                                     
----------------------+---------------------------------------------------------
schemaname            |public                                                   
tablename             |atable                                                   
attname               |a                                                        
inherited             |false                                                    
null_frac             |0.0                                                      
avg_width             |4                                                        
n_distinct            |-1.0                                                     
most_common_vals      |                                                         
most_common_freqs     |NULL                                                     
histogram_bounds      |    {1,98,196,495,593,691,789,887,985,1083,1181,1279,1377,147
correlation           |1.0                                                      
most_common_elems     |                                                         
most_common_elem_freqs|NULL                                                     
elem_count_histogram  |NULL
```

Documentation
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-stats.html